# C++ multiple inheritance, multiple definition when there isn't?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, multiple-definition-error

I'm implementing hardware drivers for an embedded C/C++ project, and trying to make things a bit more flexible for future projects.

I have the vast majority of the work done in LCD.hpp/LCD.cpp, where there's a class that has five virtual functions. Four of these are for twiddling GPIO pins and sending SPI messages, and the fifth is for implementing various fonts. A shortened class declaration is as follows:

```
//LCD.hpp
#include <cstdint>

#ifndef LCD_HPP
#define LCD_HPP
class LCD {
    public:
        virtual void write_character(char what) = 0; //Stores data into a buffer in LCD through another function
    protected:
        virtual void SPI_TX(uint8_t *TXData, uint8_t length, bool ToBeContinued) = 0;
        virtual void update_RST(bool pinstate) = 0;
        virtual void update_DC(bool pinstate) = 0;
        virtual void update_backlight(uint8_t brightness) = 0;
};
#endif
```

Moving on, I implemented a font-printing write_character as such.

```
//LCD_FixedWidth.hpp
#include <cstdint>
#include "LCD.hpp"

#ifndef LCD_FIXEDWIDTH_HPP
#define LCD_FIXEDWIDTH_HPP
class LCD_FixedWidth : virtual public LCD {
    public:
        void write_character(char what);
};
#endif
```

Now it's time for the various hardware bits.

```
//LCD_hardware.hpp
#include <cstdint>
#include "LCD.hpp"
#include "LCD_FixedWidth.hpp"

#ifndef LCD_HARDWARE_HPP
#define LCD_HARDWARE_HPP
class LCD_hardware : virtual public LCD {
    protected:
        void SPI_TX(uint8_t *TXData, uint8_t length, bool ToBeContinued);
        void update_RST(bool pinstate);
        void update_DC(bool pinstate);
        void update_backlight(uint8_t brightness);
};
```

And then a class to tie it all together, still in LCD_hardware.hpp...

```
class LCD_meta : public LCD_hardware, public LCD_FixedWidth {
    public:
        void write_character(char what) { LCD_FixedWidth::write_character(what); };
    protected:
        void SPI_TX(uint8_t *TXData, uint8_t length, bool ToBeContinued) { LCD_hardware::SPI_TX(TXData, length, ToBeContinued); };
        void update_RST(bool pinstate) { LCD_hardware::update_RST(pinstate); };
        void update_DC(bool pinstate) { LCD_hardware::update_DC(pinstate); };
        void update_backlight(uint8_t brightness) { LCD_hardware::update_backlight(brightness); };
};
#endif
```

And for all of this, I get a multiple definition of LCD_FixedWidth::write_character(char) error. Anybody see anything I'm missing here? All of my headers are guarded properly, and I can only see one implementation of write_character...

Comment: After addressing all the typos, [What seems to be broken](http://ideone.com/A96vMW) ?

Comment: Mind to provide that error message verbatim in your question please?

Comment: "multiple definition" sounds like a linker error, indicating that there are multiple definitions for the function `LCD_FixedWidth::write_character(char)`. Please search your source files and make sure there's exactly one definition of that function.

Comment: In which files do the subclasses reside?

Comment: First, you need to break this down into the simplest possible example that exhibits the behavior. Second, label each block with the name of the file in which it resides, and third, you need to give the full list of #includes for each of those files. These issues are most often an error in how your #includes are set up, and without that information, it's impossible to help. Lastly, in embedded programming, simplify. On an Arduino, for example, your above implementation blows 1% of your total memory budget just for the vtable, and that's PER INSTANCE. That not "flexible for future projects."

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having LCD_meta and LCD_hardware in the same header file. The code for the LCD_hardware functions was in an implementation file, so the LCD_meta class didn't actually have those functions defined yet... One class per file!